# clear interval on another function vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

I'm confused how to add a set Interval variable in my vue file `myTimer = setInterval(function, time)`.
The goal of my program is to change the `number` variable every 3 seconds, to access the object that I created to let it display different `background images` but I also have `2 buttons` that can `navigate` through the background as well.

This is my template code

```
<div class="background" :style="{backgroundImage: `url(${Images[`${number}`].picture})`}">
   <div class="content_container">
      <div v-on:click="prev" class="prevButton"><p>&lt;</p></div>
         <div class="title_container">
            <div class="theTitle"><p>{{Images[`${number}`].Title}}</p></div>
         </div>
      <div v-on:click="next" class="nextButton"><p>&gt;</p></div>   
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my set Interval code

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
     number: 0,
     myTimer     
  }),
  mounted:function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.timer();
    });
  },
  methods:{ 
    timer: function() {
      var myTimer = setInterval(this.counter, 3000);
  },
  counter:function(){
     if(this.number >= (this.Images.length -1)){
        this.number = 0;
     }
     else{
        this.number +=1;
     }
     },
     next()
     {
        clearInterval(this.myTimer)      
        if(this.number >= (this.Images.length -1)){
           this.number = 0;
         }
        else{
           this.number +=1;
         }
     },
```

I want to `clearInterval` at the `next()` function how can I access the variable from another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your myTimer need be in this context.

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    number: 0,
    myTimer: 0, // init myTimer
  }),
  mounted: function () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.timer();
    });
  },
  methods: {
    timer: function () {
      this.myTimer = setInterval(this.counter, 3000); // in this.myTimer
    },
    counter: function () {
      if (this.number >= this.Images.length - 1) {
        this.number = 0;
      } else {
        this.number += 1;
      }
    },
    next() {
      clearInterval(this.myTimer); // clear
      if (this.number >= this.Images.length - 1) {
        this.number = 0;
      } else {
        this.number += 1;
      }
      this.timer(); // start next
    },
  },
};
```